# Python: delete all characters before the first letter in a string

Tags: python, string

After a thorough search I could find how to delete all characters before a specific letter but not before *any* letter.

I am trying to turn a string from this:

```
"             This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace
```

To this:

```
This is a sentence. #No symbols or whitespace
```

I have tried the following code, but strings such as the first example still appear.

```
for ch in ['\"', '[', ']', '*', '_', '-']:
     if ch in sen1:
         sen1 = sen1.replace(ch,"")
```

Not only does this fail to delete the double quote in the example for some unknown reason but also wouldn't work to delete the leading whitespace as it would delete *all* of the whitespace.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of just removing white spaces, for removing any char before first letter, do this :

```
#s is your string
for i,x in enumerate(s):
    if x.isalpha()         #True if its a letter
    pos = i                   #first letter position
    break

new_str = s[pos:]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = "  sthis is a sentence"

r = re.compile(r'.*?([a-zA-Z].*)')

print r.findall(s)[0]
```

Comment: I found your regex expression very useful for what I'm trying to do. Thanks, from 4 years into the future! :)

Answer (score 1):

Strip all whitespace and punctuation:

```
>>> text.lstrip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
'This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace'
```

Or, an alternative, find the first character that is an ascii letter.  For example:

```
>>> pos = next(i for i, x in enumerate(text) if x in string.ascii_letters)
>>> text[pos:]
'This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic version; i.e. it uses syntax that beginners in Python will easily understand.

```
your_string = "1324 $$ '!'     '' # this is a sentence."
while len(your_string) > 0 and your_string[0] not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    your_string = your_string[1:]
print(your_string)

#prints "this is a sentence."
```

Pros: Simple, no imports

Cons: The while loop could be avoided if you feel comfortable using list comprehensions.
     Also, the string that you're comparing to could be simpler using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Drop everything up to the first alpha character.

```
import itertools as it


s = "      -  .] *    This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace"
"".join(it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), s))
# 'This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace'
```

Alternatively, iterate the string and test if each character is in a blacklist.  If true strip the character, otherwise short-circuit.

```
def lstrip(s, blacklist=" "):    
    for c in s:
        if c in blacklist:
            s = s.lstrip(c)
            continue
        return s

lstrip(s, blacklist='\"[]*_-. ')
# 'This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use re.sub

```
import re
text = "             This is a sentence. #contains symbol and whitespace"

re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", text)
```

re.sub(MATCH PATTERN, REPLACE STRING, STRING TO SEARCH)

Comment: this actually removes non-letter characters everywhere in the string, not only up to the first letter as required in the title of the post